# Simple thread/mutex test application is crashing

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, mingw-w64

I wrote a simple test program which accumulates random samples to a buffer using multiple threads. Each thread uses a stack for reducing the mutex waits.
This is for investigating problems in a much larger program.

The code currently crashes on mingw-w64 4.9.2

Any idea why?

Debugging halts on "signal-received" in a non-usable place (ntdll!DbgBreakPoint)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <cstdint>


//The function which will be run concurrently in several threads
void work(float * buf, uint64_t * ns, std::mutex * mtx)
{
    std::mt19937 generator;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distrib(0., 1.);
    std::vector<float> stack;
    unsigned int stackPos = 0;

    for(unsigned int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    {
        //Generate a random sample uniformly between 0 and 1
        double sample = distrib(generator);

        //Append the sample to the stack
        if(stackPos>=stack.size())
        {
            stack.resize(stackPos+1);
        }
        stack[stackPos] = sample;
        ++stackPos;

        //Try to acquire the accumulation buffer
        bool locked = mtx->try_lock();

        //Force aquire if the stack is too large and if try_lock failed
        if(!locked && stackPos>2000)
        {
            mtx->lock();
            locked = true;
        }

        //If the buffer lock is aquired, flush the stack
        if(locked)
        {
            for(unsigned int i=0;i<stackPos;i++)
            {
                *buf += stack[i];
                *ns = *ns + 1;
            }
            stackPos = 0;
            //And unlock
            mtx->unlock();
        }

    }
}


int main()
{
    float buffer = 0;
    uint64_t numSamples = 0;
    std::mutex mtx;

    //Start a couple of parallel threads
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        workers.emplace_back(std::thread(work, &buffer, &numSamples, &mtx));
    }

    //This will join the threads
    workers.clear();


    std::cout << "Average : " << buffer/numSamples << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Crashes where? On what? This is what debuggers are for.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of precision. Edited in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`workers.clear();` is not going to join all of the threads. Calling `clear()` will call the threads' deconstructors. [`std::thread::~thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) will call [`std::terminate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) if the thread is [`joinable()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable). Since you are calling `clear()` on the vector right after you create the vector the threads are still processing and are joinable.

You have to join all threads manually before deleting them:

```
int main()
{
    // […]

    //This will join the threads
    for (std::thread& thread : workers)
    {
        thread.join();
    }
    workers.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a total misconception of std::thread destruction.